# Crunchy/fried grapefruit?

Tags: food-identification

One day when I was young, we went to the doctor’s office for a checkup. While we sat in the waiting room, I was struck with curiosity by another family that was waiting. The children were eating some kind of food or snack (which I got the feeling was homemade, not store-bought). It looked just like a grapefruit (same size, shape, and color), except that instead of peeling it or cutting it in half and eating it like a regular citrus fruit, they were just taking bites out of it like an apple, right through the rind (assuming there was a rind of course). I got the distinct impression that it was dry, light, porous, and had a crunchy texture (I think I even recall an actual crunching sound), something like potato chips or cheese-puffs.

Over the years, I have often wondered what the heck they were eating. I have tried searching for it (the current top several [Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=crunchy%20grapefruit) are a bust), as well as trying to figure out how it could have been made. Assuming it was indeed a grapefruit, I considered that it may have been deep-fried (yuck‽) or “cheese-puffed” or candied or something, but none really seem plausible.

I’d love to try one, so it would be great if anyone as any leads on what it is or how to make it.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like it could be a [Nashi pear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrus_pyrifolia). It is something between an apple and a pear and is crunchy and rather dry.

Comment: Actually, a few of the [pictures of them on Google Images](http://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&q=nashi+pear) do look kind of fitting. The next time I’m at the Chinese grocery store, I’ll get one and check out its texture. (To be honest, I was really counting on it being some kind of fried snack like cheese-puffs as opposed to “just” a fruit. `˘◡˘`)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so while reading your question. However, it sounds like it's a long time so I thought it could be possible :) Let us know when you know more!

Comment: Asian Pear is the most common term for the fruit in the supermarkets in the US - some of them can be of a good size, tho perhaps a bit short of grapefruit-sized. Dry and crisp in texture and flavor, with a taste that's apple-ish and pear-ish while being neither. Delicious and relatively neat when eaten out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

> I got the distinct impression that it was dry, light, porous, and had
> a crunchy texture (I think I even recall an actual crunching sound),
> something like potato chips or cheese-puffs.

Definitely sounds like a popcorn ball.

[image: commercial popcorn ball]

They come packaged but many people make them at home. Pretty sure I have made these in preschool around halloween.

source: https://www.tasteofhome.com/recipes/traditional-popcorn-balls/

[image: from recipe]

Other flavors may be more similar to a grapefruit.

[image: other flavors]

Comment: While this seems indeed to be crunchy and round, I would never look at one of these and go "oh, this looks just like a grapefruit"

Comment: Probably depends how far away you are. They can also be coated in colored chocolate.

Comment: Also note, OP specified only "same size, shape, and color" as a grapefruit. Additionally OP stated in a comment on the pear answer: "To be honest, I was really counting on it being some kind of fried snack like cheese-puffs".